# Nested Route Not Found vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have the following code snippet of my routes from `app.js`

```js
let routes = [{
    path: "/dashboard",
    component: require("./components/Dashboard.vue")
  },
  {
    path: "/tour",
    component: require("./components/Index.vue"),
    children: [{
      name: 'create',
      path: '/create',
      component: require('./components/product/Create.vue')
    }]

  },
  {
    path: "*",
    component: require("./components/NotFound.vue")
  }
];
```

**Master.blade.php**

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <router-link class="btn btn-success" to="/dashboard">
    Dashboard
  </router-link>
  <router-link class="btn btn-success" to="/tour">
    Tour
  </router-link>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

**Index.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-5">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h3 class="card-title">Tours</h3>

            <div class="card-tools">
              <router-link class="btn btn-success" to="/tour/create">
                Add New
                <i class="fas fa-plus fa-fw"></i>
              </router-link>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.card-header -->
          <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0">
            <table class="table table-hover text-center">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Days</th>
                  <th>Price</th>
                  <th>Type</th>
                  <th>Image</th>
                  <th>Meta Title</th>
                  <th>Meta Description</th>
                  <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>

                <tr v-for="tour in tours.data" :key="tour.id">
                  <td>{{tour.id}}</td>
                  <td>{{tour.title}}</td>
                  <td>{{tour.days}}</td>
                  <td>{{tour.price}}</td>
                  <td>{{tour.category_id}}</td>
                  <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-check text-success" v-if="tour.image"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-times text-danger" v-else></i>                      
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-check text-success" v-if="tour.meta_title"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-times text-danger" v-else></i>                      
                  </td>                  
                  <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-check text-success" v-if="tour.meta_description"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-times text-danger" v-else></i>                      
                  </td>                  
                  <td>
                    <button @click="editModal(tour)" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</button>

                    <button
                      @click="deleteUser(tour.id)"
                      class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                    >Delete</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <!-- /.card-body -->
          <div class="card-footer"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        tours: ""
      };
    },
    methods: {
      initialLoad() {
        axios.get("api/tour").then(({
          data
        }) => (this.tours = data));
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.initialLoad();
    }
  };
</script>
```

**Index.vue** shows all the tours that are saved in database.

Add New button is placed in **Index.vue** to load the **Create.vue** component in order to create tours.

But clicking on the create button loads **NotFound.vue** component from `*` route. No message of any type is given out during mixing and in console.

I also tried:

`import create from './components/product/Create.vue';`

and replacing component: `require('./components/product/Create.vue')` with `create`

And still no progress.

Can anyone point out the my mistake i'm doing here.

Comment: If I'm correct, you should remove the `/` in front of `/create` in the `path` property

Comment: @daanvanham Thanks for the suggestion. I gave it a shot only the url changes from `http://localhost:3000/tour` to `http://localhost:3000/tour/create` but the **Create.vue** component doesn't loads.

Console logged in **Created.vue** component also but it doesn't show anything on click fo **Add New** button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a new file and Save by  **Tourview.vue** inside the components folder.

```
<template>
    <router-view ></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {      
      };
    },
    methods: {

  };
  };
</script>
```

and update your routing file like following.

```
let routes = [{
    path: "/dashboard",
    component: require("./components/Dashboard.vue")
  },
  {
    path: "/tour",
    component: require("./components/Tourview.vue"),
    children: [
     {
      path:'',
      component: require("./components/Index.vue")
     },
    {
      name: 'create',
      path: '/create',
      component: require('./components/product/Create.vue')
    }]

  },
  {
    path: "*",
    component: require("./components/NotFound.vue")
  }
];
```

Comment: Thanks. Do i need to update my `router-link` in **master.blade.php** also ?

Comment: only update  <router-link class="btn btn-success" to="/create">
                Add New
                <i class="fas fa-plus fa-fw"></i>
              </router-link> in index.vue file